# Is there a way to dynamically generate native x86 code and execute it from .NET?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, native, jit

I'd like to dynamically generate native unmanaged x86 code and then execute it super fast from managed .NET. I know I could emit some IL code and execute that, but I'm thinking the jetting would take too much time to get the benefit of any speed gain I get from it.

I need super fast code, I want to generate a function with the x86 opcodes in memory and pass a fixed pointer to a memory block to it, so it would make some really fast calculations on that block.

I just not sure how to call the native code from .net. remember this should be on the fly in memory, not building a dll. Speed is what really matters here. It's part of a genetic computation project.

Comment: There is no answer that can possibly help here, the fact that you are asking the question like this with seemingly no knowledge of what may be possible makes it too broad.

Comment: Maybe you don't need 100% freedom when manipulating the managed buffer. Maybe you need just a limited set of operations. In that case you can code them all in C++/CLI, and just pass some "microscript" string to the function that describes what should be done with the buffer.

Comment: Have a look at the helpful methods of the `Marshal` class, in particular `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` and `WriteByte`. You will need to mark the memory as executable for which you will need `VirtualProtect`.

Comment: It's unlikely you'd be able to generate better code than the CLR JIT can generate. If the overhead of the JIT is too expensive then overhead of your own code code generator would probably be too expensive as well.  Dynamically generating short sequences of non-looping code is never going to be super fast.

Comment: It depends on the situation. If you have control on the environment and can install compilers there you should be able to build source code in C#, compile and call the resulting binary. I am not sure if a middle man native broker DLL would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The C language is the "portable assembler" and you can generate x86 opcodes directly (writing in assembler would be better).  If you compiled the C code into an object, you could link it into .net as a library.

If you are trying to generate executable code dynamically (on-the-fly)  you would need to allocate a binary array, push the object code into the array, then get the beginning address of the array after the memory headed and assign that to a function pointer and call it.

However, antivirus software specifically looks for this behavior and would identify your code a virus more than likely.

Also your processor is designed to have "code" memory segments and "data" memory segments.  Typically you cannot dynamically modify the code segment without causing a segfault and you cannot execute out of a data segment without causing a segfault.

Also, you code would only run on a SISC processor (x86) and not on a RISC processor.

There is a lot to consider.

We used to do this in assembler in the old days on SISC systems.

Cheers,
David

Comment: Just reading your response, and you are on point. It all depends on the situation and on what level of environment control you have.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do that with C#.

You can do that with C++/CLI, by building a mixed-mode assembly that does your "super fast" calculations in native code. That way, you wouldn't need (presumably) to generate executable code "on-the-fly".

If for some reason you can't hard-code the calculation functions, then you will have to acquire executable memory from the operating system.

On Windows, you do that with the [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) and [VirtualProtect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect) functions. Again, doing that from C# would require P/Invoke interop, which would most likely reverse your speed gains.